# Relative Speed for objects moving in same direction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Points $P$ and $Q$ are $800\ \mathrm{km}$ apart. $2$ cars, $A$ and $B$, start from point $P$ and drive towards $Q$, but car $A$ starts $2$ hours before car $B$. The speeds of $A$ and $B$ are $40\ \mathrm{km/hr}$ and $60\ \mathrm{km/hr}$, respectively. $B$ overtakes $A$ at point $M$.

$1)$ After how many hours will $A$ and $B$ be separated by $50\ \mathrm{km}$ before $M$, when both are moving?
$2)$ After how many hours will $B$ be $100\ \mathrm{km}$ ahead of $A$?

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Rai and welcome to MSE. Please avoid asking those questions which demand for compleate solution and show no effort. Post your thoughts about the question and where you are getting problem. No one is here to compleate someone other's homework assignment.

Comment: Hello @THELONEWOLF. I tried my best and got answers of the other questions related to this problem so I posted the ones I couldn't solve.

The questions I did were-
1- how long will B take to overtake?
2- what is the distance from P where B overtakes A.
3 - ratio of time taken by A to B to meet at M.
4- what is the extra time required by A to reach Q
5- how many hours late A will reach at Q than that of B.

I answered these but couldn't understand the concept to solve the question posted here. Hope this helps

Comment: So it is expected that you tell the users about your work through your post. People generally downvote such questions if they don't see any effort by OP. Please add information about your work on question in future.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. this was my 1st post and I was not aware of the whole process sort of stuff here, thanks I'll keep that in mind. Have a nice day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

> after how many hours A and B will be separated by 50 km before M. when
>   both are moving.

Relative speed 20km/h which means B will advance 20km more than A every hour. At the instant when B starts the distance between A and B is 120km. Hence, B should travel 70km relative to A. So 3.5 hours will take after B starts moving which means 5.5 hours after A starts moving.

> How many hours does B require to advance himself, by 100 km, in
>   comparison to A.

As I stated above, relative speed is 20km/h. To advance by 100km B needs to travel 220km relative to A which will take 11hours after B starts moving (13.5hours after A starts moving)

Comment: shouldn't be the distance btw A and B is 80km instead of 120km?@batzorig Zorigoo